# Replacing or introducing a space after a sequence of letters some known or unknown then write on newlines content

Tags: python, file, text, replace, letter

The problem is that I now have a string where some words are sticked together:

fooledDog and I need fooled D****string text continues with inserted " "
whateveredJ and I need whatevered J*******string text continues with inserted " "

```
string = string.replace("edD","ed D")
string = string.replace("edJ","ed J")
```

but I need instead of "D" and "J" to have any possible character so to avoid hard coding values here so that the code will work with any letter or number in this position.

Comment: Can you provide a table of sample inputs and sample outputs? Depending on the complexity of the input, this may be near impossible to solve perfectly.

Comment: To clarify, you only want to put a space between lowercase `ed` follwed by a capital letter? You don't want to space out other combinations, like `"McDonalds"`=>`"Mc Donalds"` or `"educate"`=>`"ed ucate"`

Comment: yes, that is correct @Blckknght

Comment: @Blckknght your answer did the job ! I'm so excited about it, now I just need on different rows, as you have understood my example I am going to continue with it, now all I need is on one row to have text***fooled on one line then Dog***text****ed on another line/row then on another line ****text***whatevered on another line, of course the text will differ from the example: but it should end in ed or in ed) and then I need a newline and I'm done ! :)

Comment: @whtr: I'm not sure what all your \*s mean, but if my answer (or another one) solved the issue for you, then please accept it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty easy problem to solve with regular expressions (not something that is always true, even if regex are the best tool for the job). Try this:

```
import re

text = "fooledDog whateveredJob"
fixed_text = re.sub(r'ed([A-Z])', r'ed \1', text)
print(fixed_text) # prints "fooled Dog whatevered Job"
```

The pattern looks for the letters `'ed'` in lowercase, followed by any capital letter (which gets captured). The replacement is `'ed'` and a space, followed by the capital letter from the capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but it seems you have some camelCase words you wanna separate. If that's the case, try this:

```
import re

name = 'CamelCaseTest123'
splitted = re.sub('(?!^)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', name).split()
```

**Output:**

```
['Camel', 'Case', 'Test123']
```